# Android studio keeps telling me that the factory class needs a body, what could be wrong?

Tags: flutter, api, android-studio, dart, factory

```
class WallpaperModel{

  late String photographer;
  late String photographer_url;
  late int photographer_id;
  SrcModel src;

  WallpaperModel({ required this.src, required this.photographer_url,required this.photographer_id, required this.photographer})

  factory WallpaperModel.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> jsonData){
    return WallpaperModel(src: jsonData['src'],
        photographer_url: jsonData['photographer_url'],
        photographer_id: jsonData['photographer_id'],
        photographer: jsonData['photographer']);
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement Pexels API into a wallpaper application but Android studio is flagging the factory class as an error that it needs a body. What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a missing semicolon `;` on this line.

```
  WallpaperModel({ required this.src, required this.photographer_url,required this.photographer_id, required this.photographer});
```